# Sorting choises in a choice field

Tags: list, choice-field

In an old list, new choises has been added in a choice field. Now, I want to sort them.

Will this affect  the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how choice columns work from my experience. The values you have can be re-ordered as long as the values don't change. Choice menus give users new choices when an item is modified and if the choice list is missing choices or has new ones that is the choice list users can use upon saving an item. Items that had old values will retain them until they are modified even if you remove a choice from a choice menu.

Lookup columns are dynamic where if you make a change it will change all existing values. Choice columns are not dynamic when changes are made.